# structlog bind method remembers previous user and logs with user_id, but after request finished it's not being cleared

Tags: django, structlog

I have bind user_id with structlog to log user_id like following in a middleware

```
class StructlogMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        req = set_request_user(request)
        user_id = getattr(request.user, 'id', None)
        structlog.get_logger('django_structlog.middlewares.RequestMiddleware').bind(user_id=user_id)
        bind_threadlocal(user_id=user_id)
```

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    "user_mngmt_app.custom_middleware.StructlogMiddleware",
    "django_structlog.middlewares.RequestMiddleware",
    ....
]
```

for the first request made after app started, it logs prefectly,
it logs user_id=None before request is started, and prints actual id after request is started.

Problem is for further requests, it logs previous user_id before request started, while it should be None.
Id after request started is always ok.

I want to reset/remove/clear user cached data after request is done.

From below, Before request start all logs prints without user_id. Request was made with valid token.

```
2023-12-19T10:14:05.016552Z [info     ] set_request_user: begins       [user_mngmt_app.middleware] 
2023-12-19T10:14:05.016839Z [debug    ] set_request_user: args: (<WSGIRequest: GET '/api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656'>,) kwargs: {} [user_mngmt_app.middleware] 
2023-12-19T10:14:05.017030Z [info     ] While setting user request....settings.CACHE_URL: redis://localhost:6379 [user_mngmt_app.middleware] 
2023-12-19T10:14:05.025294Z [info     ] While setting user request is done....settings.CACHE_URL: redis://localhost:6379 [user_mngmt_app.middleware] 
2023-12-19T10:14:05.025804Z [debug    ] set_request_user: result: <WSGIRequest: GET '/api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656'> [user_mngmt_app.middleware] 
2023-12-19T10:14:05.026114Z [info     ] set_request_user: Required time: 9.302616119384766ms [user_mngmt_app.middleware] 
2023-12-19T10:14:05.026391Z [info     ] set_request_user: ends         [user_mngmt_app.middleware] 
2023-12-19T10:14:05.029685Z [info     ] request_started                [django_structlog.middlewares.request] ip=127.0.0.1 request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656'> request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_agent=PostmanRuntime/7.36.0 user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.032650Z [info     ] Serializer validation started. request.GET:<QueryDict: {'business_account_number_tp': ['01856565656']}> [loan_mngmt_app.views.tp_client_data_view] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.035175Z [debug    ] Finding proper tc client takes: 0.001483917236328125s [loan_mngmt_app.serializers.tp_client_data_serializer] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.669211Z [debug    ] Get tp client takes: 0.633798360824585s [loan_mngmt_app.serializers.tp_client_data_serializer] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.669903Z [debug    ] Serializer validation takes 0.6372725963592529. request.GET:<QueryDict: {'business_account_number_tp': ['01856565656']}> [loan_mngmt_app.views.tp_client_data_view] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.670497Z [info     ] Data processing started. request.GET:<QueryDict: {'business_account_number_tp': ['01856565656']}> [loan_mngmt_app.views.tp_client_data_view] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.676245Z [info     ] Cache set done for user: 2     [user_mngmt_app.utilities.cache_management_utilities] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.684940Z [debug    ] Time to create request body: 0.00789499282836914s [loan_mngmt_app.services.tp_data_saving_to_tc_service] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.685207Z [debug    ] Data processing takes 0.014761209487915039s. request.GET:<QueryDict: {'business_account_number_tp': ['01856565656']}> [loan_mngmt_app.views.tp_client_data_view] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.685777Z [debug    ] TPClientDataDetailsView().get_details() takes: 0.6532118320465088 [loan_mngmt_app.views.tp_client_data_view] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.685997Z [info     ] Building response while request.GET:<QueryDict: {'business_account_number_tp': ['01856565656']}> [loan_mngmt_app.views.tp_client_data_view] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.686254Z [info     ] Building data for client_id:479694032935590779 [loan_mngmt_app.services.client_data_fetch_service] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.686448Z [info     ] Getting cache for data_point   [utils.services.caching] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.693192Z [info     ] Cache get for data_point Successfully [utils.services.caching] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.695161Z [debug    ] ClientDataFetchForTKAppService().get_details() takes: 0.008940458297729492 [loan_mngmt_app.views.tp_client_data_view] ip=127.0.0.1 request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:14:05.695684Z [info     ] request_finished               [django_structlog.middlewares.request] code=200 ip=127.0.0.1 request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656'> request_id=4fe80988-92a3-4a29-9ac0-fddbf9cfce5e user_id=2
[19/Dec/2023 16:14:05] "GET /api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656 HTTP/1.1" 200 6267
```

Then made a request without toke. user_id should be None. But before request started it log prints previous user_id, then sets it to None

```
2023-12-19T10:15:49.742164Z [debug    ] set_request_user: args: (<WSGIRequest: GET '/api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656'>,) kwargs: {} [user_mngmt_app.middleware] user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:15:49.742335Z [info     ] While setting user request....settings.CACHE_URL: redis://localhost:6379 [user_mngmt_app.middleware] user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:15:49.743243Z [info     ] While setting user request is done....settings.CACHE_URL: redis://localhost:6379 [user_mngmt_app.middleware] user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:15:49.743502Z [debug    ] set_request_user: result: <WSGIRequest: GET '/api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656'> [user_mngmt_app.middleware] user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:15:49.743677Z [info     ] set_request_user: Required time: 1.5571117401123047ms [user_mngmt_app.middleware] user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:15:49.743832Z [info     ] set_request_user: ends         [user_mngmt_app.middleware] user_id=2
2023-12-19T10:15:49.744337Z [info     ] request_started                [django_structlog.middlewares.request] ip=127.0.0.1 request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656'> request_id=6b23eb47-5846-4289-9d53-150f9e36d2b0 user_agent=PostmanRuntime/7.36.0 user_id=None
2023-12-19T10:15:49.745345Z [info     ] request_finished               [django_structlog.middlewares.request] code=401 ip=127.0.0.1 request=<WSGIRequest: GET '/api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656'> request_id=6b23eb47-5846-4289-9d53-150f9e36d2b0 user_id=None
Unauthorized: /api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details
[19/Dec/2023 16:15:49] "GET /api/loan/tp-client-data/tk-app/details?business_account_number_tp=01856565656 HTTP/1.1" 401 58
```